# Error ENDABAP is not defined in eCATT Script

Tags: abap, sap-basis

When I want to use the abap endabap block in eCATT script, I have this error message :

Syntax Error in Inline ABAP

> Statement "ENDABAP" is not defined. Check your spelling.

This is my test script:

```
TCD ( me21 , me21_1 ).
LOG ( pe_ca ).

ABAP.
  DATA : lv_matkl TYPE matkl.
* SELECT du groupe de marchandise
  SELECT SINGLE matkl 
  INTO lv_matkl 
  FROM EKPO 
  WHERE ebeln = PV_CA.
ENDABAP.
```

All prerequisites have been done (table `T000`, `RZ11`, ...).

Comment: Where does `PV_CA` come from?

Comment: you don't provide both keys for EKPO, so a select single with one key is dangerous. Did you "Test script → Check → Extended"? From the documentation: "We recommend that you place inline ABAP in a separate script and call it from the main script using the REF command."